# Delete an instance of the object

Tags: python, object, instance, sleep

I'm trying to understand the class notion in Python and having decided to do a little exercise I found myself facing a problem.

What I'm trying to do is to create a circle (on a left-click) and then I expect the program to delete the circle (on a right-click).

Well, here comes the second part of my problem.

My code:

```
from tkinter import *

class Application:
    def __init__(self):
        self.fen = Tk()
        self.fen.title('Rom-rom-roooooom')
        self.butt1 = Button(self.fen, text = ' Quit ', command = self.fen.quit)
        self.can1 = Canvas(self.fen, width = 300, height = 300, bg = 'ivory')
        self.can1.grid(row = 1)
        self.butt1.grid(row = 2)
        self.fen.bind("<Button-1>", self.create_obj)
        self.fen.bind("<Button-3>", self.delete_obj)
        self.fen.mainloop()
    def create_obj(self, event):
        self.d = Oval()
        self.can1.create_oval(self.d.x1, self.d.y1, self.d.x2, self.d.y2, fill='red', width = 2)
    def delete_obj(self, event):
        self.can1.delete(self.d)


class Oval:

    def __init__(self):
        self.x1 = 50
        self.y1 = 50
        self.x2 = 70
        self.y2 = 70


appp = Application()
```

Here, the program understands that 'd' is an instance of class Oval, but it doesn't delete the object on a right click:

```
def delete_obj(self, event):
    self.can1.delete(self.d)
```

Comment: This isn't really about classes in Python, but about the behaviour of a specific method (create_oval) in Tkinter. In general, I would not recommend TK as a good example of classes in Python anyway.

Comment: +1 to @DanielRoseman's comment: I would also not recommend TK as a good example of, well, anything.

Comment: in this case what would you recommend as a GUI library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the tkinter docs, `create_oval` returns an object id, which is an integer. To remove the circle, use the `Canvas.delete` method:

```
from tkinter import *

import time

class Application:
    def __init__(self):
        self.fen = Tk()
        self.fen.title('Rom-rom-roooooom')
        self.butt1 = Button(self.fen, text = ' Quit ', command = self.fen.quit)
        self.can1 = Canvas(self.fen, width = 300, height = 300, bg = 'ivory')
        self.can1.grid(row = 1)
        self.butt1.grid(row = 2)
        self.fen.bind("<Button-1>", self.create_obj)
        self.fen.mainloop()

    def create_obj(self, event):
        d = self.can1.create_oval(150,150, 170, 170, fill='red', width = 2)
        time.sleep(3)
        self.can1.delete(d)

appp = Application()
```

Comment: I've tried to optimize the code I'd written above, but a new problem occured. Could you possibly have a look at this? I've edited the text of my first message

Comment: @SergeTelnov Please ask that as a new question, so more people will look at it.